# Facebook status.get API throws 500 HTTP status code

Tags: rest, facebook

I have an APP that calls Facebook status.get method via the REST server - restserver.php using session key method. This app works fine for most of the users, but for one user I consistently receive HTTP 500 status code. Since this doesn't have any specific Facebook error message, it is almost impossible for me to debug this.

Anyone faced a similar problem? What could be wrong with this user account? I checked the privacy options that I could think of and they look fine.

Also, for the same user, I can use friends.get method without any problem.

EDIT: I tried in Facebook forums as well, but it was of no use. Any pointers in the direction towards debugging/troubleshooting this problem are also appreciated.

EDIT: The full HTTP trace of my request is as follows. Just to be clear the same code works for other users.

```
REQUEST
=======================
GET /restserver.php?method=facebook.status.get&limit=1&api_key=a134957738cbd097e76bcefee86c75db&v=1.0&call_id=8cc99cec1562a71&format=JSON&session_key=747ad19e9859993f97c20355-1038949180&sig=5f597e80ad081b30c7155e9176a2aa04 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Pandemonium
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: api.facebook.com


RESPONSE
=======================
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-type: application/json
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
P3P: CP="DSP LAW"
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: datr=1269479340-0545d70990e5f2db3b59176d82435f687f48a4bc69b5f11be9364; expires=Sat, 24-Mar-2012 01:09:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com
X-Cnection: close
Date: Thu, 25 Mar 2010 01:09:32 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: can you provide the line of code for your query? Just the actual URL you use for the status.get method.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just added the description field to my API call. When I deleted the description from my fields the server error was fixed. No idea why it can't handle the description field.

```
$events = $this->facebook->api('/me/events?fields=name,venue,privacy,location');
```

Answer (score 0):

The user had already approved the status.get permissions?

Comment: Yes, but ... this is a comment; not an answer.